# How to set tint for an text view programmatically in android?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to set the tintList programatically in the Android app for both imageView and textView. The code works for imageView but dosent work for textView.
I have tried using the following code.

```
//Defining myColorStateList
myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_selected},
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}
                },
                new int[]{
                        ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.red)
                        ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.blue)
                }
        );

//Works for imageView 
myImageView.setImageTintList(myColorStateList);

//The TextView picks up the tintList defined in xml, dosent apply the one being set programatically
myTextView.setCompoundDrawableTintList(myColorStateList);
```

What I have tried so far: In al cases the tintList defined in the myTextView resource file is being used, its not changed to the one being set programatically. I am looking to update the tint list for both imageView and the textView.

I am using the colorStateList here so that the views change colors when selected and unselected.

1. myTextView.setCompoundDrawableTintList(null); - same result
2. myTextView.setTextColor(null); - same result
3. myTextView.setCompoundDrawableTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST); - same result

Thanks for looking and your time.

Comment: Use setColorFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myTextView.setTextColor(myColorStateList)
```

was the appropriate API to be used for the TextView in this case